# Quando usar Layout Relativo ou Linear?

Tags: android, android-xml

Estou na dúvida de quando usar `LayoutRelativo` ou `Linear`? Qual vantagem de usar em cada caso.

Comment: dá uma olhada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905370/what-are-the-differences-between-linearlayout-relativelayout-and-absolutelayou)

Comment: Nunca, sempre use `ConstraintLayout`

Answer (score 1):

### LinearLayout

É indicado quando você quer alinhar os componentes em série, seja ela vertical ou horizontal. A imagem a seguir mostra um layout com orientação horizontal (os 3 componentes estão lado a lado):

[image: Exemplo de componentes em um LinearLayout]

Fonte: [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/images/ui/linearlayout.png)

---

### RelativeLayout

Serve para posicionar os componentes de modo que um esteja relativo à outro. A imagem a seguir mostra isso, com o primeiro componente alinhado ao topo, outros dois abaixo dele, sendo um à esquerda e outro à direita do layout pai:

[image: Exemplo de componentes em um RelativeLayout]

Fonte: [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative)

---

### Recomendação

Está disponível o `ConstraintLayout`, que é uma evolução significativa do `RelativeLayout`. Ele permite muito mais flexibilidade no desenvolvimento, e é recomendado em favor das alternativas citadas.

Outra opção é o `CoordinatorLayout`, muito útil na composição de layouts que contém `AppBars` e/ou `FloatingActionButtons`, facilitando a criação de animações e componentes mais responsivos.